# Java: How to design a class which needs several properties from its child to process a file?

Tags: java, csv, oop, design-patterns

I have a requirement as follows:

1. Read data from CSV file.
2. Find duplicate rows based on key passed. (Say example, CSV file has 10 columns, we need to find duplicates based on a particular row
   key)
3. A boolean to reject/accept duplicate rows.
4. Cell Processors to validate each row in the file.

This is for a bulk upload data where I read the file row by row, find if the row has valid data and the row is not duplicate based on key passed and finally return a list of valid rows.

```
abstract class BulkUploadService {
     List<BulkDTO> process(File file) {
       // Read a file and the value from below methods overridden by their child classes
     }

     abstract CellProcessors[] cellProcessors();
     abstract boolean isDuplicatesAllowed();
     abstract String[] headers();
     abstract String rowKey();
 }
```

The method process() needs - **File, Row key, CellProcessors, boolean to accept/reject duplicates, and few more** to process and return a list of valid rows in the form of DTOs. The child classes will implement `BulkUploadService` and override all the methods except process() to supply data for the process() method to return a valid list.

The reason I want to abstract out is this `BulkUploadService` should handle all the business logic and return a valid list for the concrete classes and the concrete classes should focus just on supplying information. Is there a better way to design for this scenario?

Comment: I did not get the problem quite... If CellProcessors are defined to validate the data, why don't you define another CellProcessor to validate duplicates?

Comment: @AnandVaidya probably `isDuplicatesAllowed` is the way to tune `CellProcessors[]` logic

Comment: yeah.. read the question again and got the point.

Comment: @AnandVaidya we read every row in the csv file using `CSVBeanReader`. The use of `CellProcessors` is to validate every column when reading a row.  We will be a constructing a list or map and add this row to the list if all the columns are valid. The use of `isDuplicatesAllowed` is not to add a row when a particular row with a `rowkey` is already read and also remove the row that has added to the list or map. We will be finally returning `List<BulkDTO>` or `Map<String, BulkDTO>` I hope this clears.

Answer (score 5):

I am not a big fan of inheritance and [don't understand why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) you are using it here.

You've clearly defined two responsibilities:

- processing data (1);
- collecting requisite parts for processing (2).

Now, your subclasses are supposed to take both responsibilities, [which is not correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I suggest you design separate classes for (1) and (2).

```
class BulkUploadService {
     private BulkUploadDataCollector collector;

     List<BulkDTO> process(File file) { ... }
}

interface BulkUploadDataCollector {
     CellProcessors[] cellProcessors();
     boolean isDuplicatesAllowed();
     String[] headers();
     String rowKey();
}
```

If you scrutinise `BulkUploadDataCollector`, you will notice that it's up to fetch and store data (too many duties again).

I would write a DTO class (let's say `BulkUploadData`) which will free `BulkUploadDataCollector` (now, renamed to `BulkUploadDataFetcher`) from storing data and loosen the coupling between `BulkUploadDataFetcher` and `BulkUploadDataService`.

These two wouldn't know about each other and would work exclusively through `BulkUploadData` instances.

Comment: Hey Andrew, Thanks for the beautiful approach right above. Can you please be a bit elaborate on how do you use BulkUploadData and its structure.

Comment: I imagine `BulkUploadData` as a POJO class with 4 fields and corresponding accessor methods (though, the class could be immutable). The main purpose of it is to transfer data between `Fetcher` and `Service`. `Fetcher` has a method that produces a constructed `BulkUploadData` instance, `Service` has a method/constructor that takes such objects.

Comment: @Bargath I'll illustrate this idea with code a bit later